# Did Bones and The Finder ever get a franchise title?

Tags: bones

When *The Finder* was spun off from *Bones* did the two series ever get a franchise title or is the franchise title *Bones* because *The Finder* only had thirteen episodes?

Comment: Or maybe it just doesn't have one at all.

Comment: That is what I am wondering, @NapoleonWilson.

Comment: I was excluding *Bones* being used as a franchise title, too, i.e. there might not actually be a genuine franchise at all here, since not every spin-off creates a cinematic multiverse. But that'll be part of the answer, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

...but then a "franchise" essentially requires that the two series have some commonality be it the same organisation (e.g. NCIS) or the same basic premise (e.g. CSI).

In this case the two series did not share this commonality but they do share the same TV *universe*.

By way of further example, NCIS is a spin-off of the highly successful series *JAG* but we don't refer to the combined *JAG/NCIS* franchise....they share a universe (and continue to do so) but they are not a **single** "franchise".

Comment: I was using the term "franchise" loosely here because TV series series (a series of TV series, akin to a film series) may have been a tad confusing. *Cheers* and its spin-offs *The Tortellis* and *Frasier* are not a franchise, but I would probably use the word franchise because TV series series sounds wrong.